# Decomposition $Y=\text{im}T \oplus N$ for Fredholm operator $T$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I don't get how, from the definition of Fredholm Operator below, we get $Y=\text{im}T \oplus N$ with $N$ closed?

[image]

Example 11.6(1) states Finite-Dimensional subspaces are always complemented.

Example 11.6(2) states Finite-Codimensional *Closed* subspaces are complemented.

Example 11.4(1) states if $T:X\rightarrow Y$ is an operator, $X,Y$ are Banach, and $Y=\text{im}T \oplus N$ with $N$ closed, then $\text{im}T$ is also closed.

How can 11.4(1) help us? it seems to assume precisely what we want to prove...

Comment: finite dimensional spaces are closed. idk how those examples are relevant.

Comment: @mathworker21 $imT$ may not be finite-dimensional, from what I understood, but has finite codimension.

Comment: maybe the following argument works: $Y/imT \cong ker T$, so since $ker T$ closed, $Y/imT$ closed (the isomorphism should be continuous), so $im T$ closed

Comment: @mathworker21 the only theorem similar to that, which I know is the 1st isomorphism theorem, but with $kerT$ interchanged with $imT$... Is that a known theorem or property?

Comment: oops, of course. I'll come back to this.

Comment: @mathworker21 by the way, check this my other question related to this... I think  it can help us both. ;) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307828/why-is-the-closed-im-t-in-the-definition-of-fredholm-operator-redundant